# Java splitting read lines into strings and then using them

Tags: java, string, if-statement, io

so i have the code

```
public void reply(){
    String fileName = "readLog.txt";
    String line = null;
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Output.append(line);//output is name of textarea
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
    }                   
    }
```

and it reads out what is in the text file fine but I want it to read
say line 1, and in line 1 I would have something like:

> A Question        -          A answer

and I want it so It can place the lines in the correct places e.g

> if("Input" == "A Question") { somethinghappends(); }

I know thats not how you would set out a if statment with strings it is just an example.

how would I go about doing this? (ive looked around the internet and haven't found much of use)

Comment: What's in readLog.txt ?

Comment: I havent got much in there at the moment but for example I would put "what is your name - my name is bob"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split("-");

    if (parts.length >= 2 && parts[0].trim().equals(parts[1].trim())) {
        doSomethingHere();
    }
}
```

I also use [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to remove leading and trailing spaces around the question and the answer before comparing them.

Answer (score 2):

If your format is:

A question - An answer,

You can do something like:

```
String[] parts = line.split(" - ");
String question = parts[0];
String answer = parts[1];
```

Considering that the dash is the separator. This one is in the loop that reads every line.

Comment: ok thats fine but how do I get it so it reads only a line at a time because currently It reads out everything in the text file?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a question String and want to find the fitting answer in readLog.

The best way would be splitting your answers at " - ". (A better seperator would be "\t" since " - " could also be a part of the question/answer.)

```
String q="question";
String qa="question - answer";
String[] split = qa.split(" - ");
if(split[0].equals(q)){
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bufferedreader.readline()` method to read from the stream until you find your desired line. Get the data and process on it. You might use the `equals()` method for comparison. You can finally part your string using `split()` and store it in array.